# Using Greek farina (cake flour) instead of yeast for making bread whilst combined with general puproce flour

Tags: substitutions, bread, flour, yeast

I have some leftover general-puproce flour and some farina, because are leftover materials and I wanna use them both (in order to get rid of them, but not throw them away) I thought on making bread by combining both of them.

Usually farina is used on making cakes, cookies etc etc and while is used, instead of general-puproce flour, yeast in not used because it has the tedency to expand by itself.

So in my case that I want to cook them, by combining them to both to my bread mixture, should I avoid using yeast or baking powder?

## edit 1

By farina I mean a self-expanding flour used in cakes. Because of misunderstadning that "farina" word brings here is an [image](https://supermarket24.gr/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/%CE%A6%CE%B1%CF%81%CE%AF%CE%BD%CE%B1-%CE%9A%CF%8C%CE%BA%CE%BA%CE%B9%CE%BD%CE%B7-%CE%93%CE%B9%CF%8E%CF%84%CE%B7%CF%82-500-g-010%E2%82%AC.jpg) of it as sold in Greece and seen in Greek Supermarkets.

Comment: I'm not familiar with *farina* as an English word, but in other languages it simply means *flour*. So it's not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: I placed extra description for farina.

Comment: That sounds like *self-raising flour* (British English) or *self-rising flour* (American).

Comment: Well yes it is actually self raising flour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've clarified that *farina* is self-raising flour, you can use it in quick breads (soda breads). You can probably find a recipe that uses just this flour with no other leavening agents.

The plain flour would need something to make it rise. This should either be yeast or the chemical leaveners in the other flour, however if you just mix the two you won't have enough for much rise. So either add baking powder for a quick bread, add yeast for a traditional bread, or use it to make flatbread.

Comment: So I should still use yeast or soda right? 

But that depends on mixture ratio for example If my general puproce flour is on 60% per weight and the farina is on 40% then it should be enough to expand by itself, right?

Comment: If you insist on mixing them, I suggest you find a recipe using self raising flour then convert the plain flour to self raising by adding baking powder. Unlike yeast, chemical leaveners don't multiply so less than about 90% self raising is likely to be disappointing in a recipe that calls for 100%